# subview inside pdfView.documentView keeps disappearing

Tags: swift, subview, pdfview

I have the following code:

```
let subView = UIView(frame: .init(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
subView.backgroundColor = .red

self.pdfView.layoutDocumentView()
self.pdfView.documentView?.addSubview(subView)
self.pdfView.documentView?.bringSubviewToFront(subView)
```

The view is added successfully. But, when I scroll down, say 10 pages, and then go back to page 1, `subview` disappears.

Any suggestions on how can I make it appear permanently?

I know I can add an annotation instead of a view. But, I need to enable user interactions on the view.

[PDFView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfview) documentation from apple